# Add image alt text to The Stack Overflow Comment Evaluator 5000

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, comments, accessibility, comment-evaluator-5000

I was trying to evaluate some comments on the The Stack Overflow Comment Evaluator 5000, but the images aren't loading for me.  I'm pretty sure it's my fault the images aren't rendering, but it would be nice if the images had alt text to get around this issue.  Also, the alt text is better for accessibility reasons.

> [image: Comment Evaluator 5000]

Comment: Who's site is this??

Comment: I got an email from `comment-classification@stackoverflow.email` ?  Did I just get phished?

Comment: @Makoto It was sent as an email, it's basically jsut getting more users for the rating comments project/thing that was in the blog a short while back.

Comment: @ryanyuyu The email said to send bugs to them, btw, directly- This might count, idk. (Also, the three buttons are in order if that helps. Fine is on the left, disrespectful/unfriendly in the middle, abusive/harrassment on the right.

Comment: I mean the big thing for me is that the site takes you to a site that isn't a Stack Exchange domain.  I'm not sure how they'd phish you unless you had to authenticate to the site (in that case you need to change your password(s)).  I've never heard of this site until today.  Something seems *suspect*.

Comment: Completely missed that final line on the email.  I'm so used to posting bug reports here on MSO.

Comment: @Makoto both the email and the site claimed to need an actual SO profile becuase "The comment evaluator app relies on the Stack Overflow API, which requires an account. If you don't have a Stack Overflow account, you should make one."

Comment: @Makoto I felt the same, before I looked into it all. All the red flags checked out as a false-positive to me. (And if I'm wrong, then yep, I need to change credentials.) It does indeed require authentication.

Comment: \*shudders\*  Yeah, something doesn't seem right here, y'all.

Comment: Because if so, this is a really well designed phishing email.

Comment: Man, I even found other images of the "Comment Evaluator 5000" on other official SO stuff, and this replicated it really well.

Comment: @ryanyuyu:  That's kind of the objective with phishing emails, so...I mean Kendra's pretty reputable around these parts, but still...if phishing were one's objective, Mission Accomplished™?

Comment: It's a legit email. But just this email; if you get any other emails asking you to log in with your SE account, report 'em please.

Comment: @Shog9:  Got any more details?

Comment: @Shog9 ok thanks.  I was just about to edit this into a different kind of post.  Can I just leave this feature request here?

Comment: Sure, why not. I'll toss a link to the folks behind this project.

Comment: @Makoto see: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/314790/please-host-the-stack-overflow-comment-evaluator-5000-under-stack-overflow-doma/314794#314794

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Thanks for the report. This is fixed now.